# how to parse certificate information in Python

Tags: python

Now I am tring to parse a url certificate in Python 3, this is my Python code:

```
class CertUtil:

    @staticmethod
    def check_cert_imp(domain):
        string_io = StringIO()
        parsed_url = urlparse(domain)
        if parsed_url.scheme == '' or parsed_url is None:
            domain = domain + "https://"
        comm = f"curl -Ivs {domain} --connect-timeout 10"
        result = subprocess.getstatusoutput(comm)
        string_io.write(result[1])
        cert_result = re.search('start date: (.*?)\n.*?expire date: (.*?)\n.*?common name: (.*?)\n.*?issuer: CN=(.*?)\n', string_io.getvalue(), re.S)
        if cert_result is None:
            logger.error("cert result is null:" + domain)
            return None
        start_date = cert_result.group(1)
        expire_date = cert_result.group(2)
        common_name = cert_result.group(3)
        issuer = cert_result.group(4)
```

to my suprise, the `cert_result` always return `None`. Where I am going wrong? what should I do to parse it correctly? BTW, what I am trying to parse domain is: `https://admin.poemhub.top`. the `string_io.getvalue()` is:

```
*   Trying 121.196.199.223:443...
* Connected to admin.poemhub.top (121.196.199.223) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [112 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3815 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [115 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.poemhub.top
*  start date: Jul 12 03:06:28 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 10 03:06:27 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "admin.poemhub.top" matched cert's "*.poemhub.top"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: admin.poemhub.top
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.20.1
< Date: Sun, 25 Jul 2021 05:46:29 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 4357
< Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Jun 2021 10:53:59 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "60d312c7-1105"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
* Connection #0 to host admin.poemhub.top left intact
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Sun, 25 Jul 2021 05:46:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 4357
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Jun 2021 10:53:59 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "60d312c7-1105"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `string_io.getvalue()`?

Comment: I have pasted the `string_io.getvalue()` value.@purple

Comment: Your regex does not appear in `string_io.getvalue()`. For example, the string "common name" is not in `string_io.getvalue()`. Therefore, `re.search(...)` returns `None`.

Comment: First thing to note is that you should review your code after urlparse(). You should check for None before trying to dereference it. Also, the domain modification is inverted. That aside, it looks like the issue is with your regular expression. Try breaking it down into discrete steps - i.e. get 'start date' then 'expire date' and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried `curl -Ivs "https://admin.poemhub.top" --connect-timeout 10"` , and the interesting part or the result is this:

```
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.poemhub.top
*  start date: Jul 12 03:06:28 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 10 03:06:27 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "admin.poemhub.top" matched cert's "*.poemhub.top"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
```

So your regex string is almost right, except for 2 things:

- `common name:` part is missing, I'd make it "optional" by `(?:common name: (.*?)\n.*?)?` (wrap optional match in `(?: ... )`
- there's text after `issuer:` before `CN=` so I'd fix it to `issuer: .*?CN=(.*?)\n` (mind the `.*?` part before `CN=`)

Then the resulting regex string should be:

```
start date: (.*?)\n.*?expire date: (.*?)\n.*?(?:common name: (.*?)\n.*?)?issuer: .*?CN=(.*?)\n
```

(mind that `common_name` that is `group(3)` of result may contain `None` now in the case it is missing)

**Unrelated to question** I think you made a mistake in `domain = domain + "https://"` which should be `domain = "https://" + domain` (you want to prepend protocol to the domain, not domain to the protocol).

Comment: It should work for now, but I also support Andy Knight's comment that you should parse each line with a separate regular expression since the order may eventually change.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your original question but you can use [ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert) to parse the SSL certificate:

**test.py:**

```
import pprint
import socket
import ssl


HOSTNAME = "admin.poemhub.top"

def main():
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET) as s:
        conn = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=HOSTNAME)
        conn.connect((HOSTNAME, 443))
        cert = conn.getpeercert()

    pprint.pprint(cert)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
{'OCSP': ('http://r3.o.lencr.org',),
 'caIssuers': ('http://r3.i.lencr.org/',),
 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'US'),),
            (('organizationName', "Let's Encrypt"),),
            (('commonName', 'R3'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Oct 10 03:06:27 2021 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Jul 12 03:06:28 2021 GMT',
 'serialNumber': '04EAC6ED15CFE60424FD96AD9B24D9293D4E',
 'subject': ((('commonName', '*.poemhub.top'),),),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', '*.poemhub.top'),),
 'version': 3}
```